# Removing a vertex to find a graph's independent set

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I am in an algorithms class in grad school, and I have an assignment to "prove or disprove" a specific algorithm.  This algorithms is supposed provide the maximum size independent set.

At each step we choose one vertex $u$ to remove that has the lowest degree in the current graph, and we add that vertex to the independent set we are building. I also remove the vertices adjacent to $u$ as well as all edges incident to those vertices.

Does that automatically update the degrees of any remaining vertices? I know it is most likely a stupid question, but I struggle with algorithms.

Comment: sure, I start off with let's say a 12 vertex connected, the given algorithm uses a greedy method to remove the vertex with the minimum degree and the adjacent vertexes, which I assume will remove the edges connecting those vertices. So my question is after removing those vertices and edges, does that change the degree of the remaining vertices that are affected by the removal of the edge?

Comment: the point is to prove that there is a maximum length independent set

Comment: There is some confusion in your description of the algorithm. An independent set is a set of vertices no two of which are adjacent, i.e. which have no common edge.  Therefore "length" is misleading in describing an independent set; probably what you mean is an independent set of maximum size.  In any case you began by saying that this algorithm removes "one vertex at a time".  The idea that you are removing its edges and neighbors at the same time does make sense but conflicts with how you described the algorithm.  Readers rely on you to describe the algorithm you want to ask about.

Comment: I was able to get my answer, thank you for your help. As I stated I struggle with this subject.

Comment: I'm going to try my hand at editing the Question to ask about the algorithm a little more clearly.  Please advise if you find I inadvertently changed your meaning.

Comment: Note that as @Yikai implies, this algorithm will *not* invariably produce a *maximum* size independent set.  It will however produce a *maximal* independent set, i.e. an independent set that is not contained in any larger independent set of vertices.  Possibly your assignment may originally have been intended to produce a "disproof" in the form of an example where the algorithm fails to get a maximum size independent set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You should update the degree of remaining vertices after removing the vertex with minimum degree and its adjacent edges. This generally can lead to a larger independent set than that obtained if you do not do so. Please also note that there does not exist a polynomial-time algorithm with constant approximation ratio unless $\mathsf{P} =\mathsf{NP}$. You can employ a minimum heap which supports updating keys to maintain the vertices.